# How to get displays myArray after X-value is true?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to create a program where if the user enters a X-number between 1-9, and it takes that X-number and creates X-number of rows and columns. For example, if the user enters "5", the output should be something like this:

....1
...2.
..3..
.4...
5....

I cannot get it to show the output right now with the code I have. I am still new to JavaScript so any help is appreciated.

```js
function drawSquare() {
let myArray1 = ["1"];
let myArray2 = [".1", "2."];
let myArray3 = ["..1", ".2.", "3.."];
let myArray4 = ["...1", "..2.", ".3..", "4..."];
let myArray5 = ["....1", "...2.", "..3..", ".4...", "5...."];
let myArray6 = [".....1", "....2.", "...3..", "..4...", ".5....", "6....."];
let myArray7 = ["......1", ".....2.", "....3..", "...4...", "..5....", ".6.....", "7......"];
let myArray8 = [".......1", "......2.", ".....3..", "....4...", "...5....", "..6.....", ".7......", "8......."];
let myArray9 = ["........1", ".......2.", "......3..", ".....4...", "....5....", "...6.....", "..7......", ".8.......", "9........"];
let l1 = myArray1.length;
let l2 = myArray2.lenght;
let l3 = myArray3.length;
let l4 = myArray4.length;
let l5 = myArray5.length;
let l6 = myArray6.length;
let l7 = myArray7.length;
let l8 = myArray8.length;
let l9 = myArray9.length;
let number = document.getElementById("textbox3")
let getNumber = number.value 
if (getNumber != 1 || getNumber > 9) {
 alert("You have entered an incorrect number");
 } else if (getNumber = 1){
  text = "<br>";
   for (i = 0; i < l1; i++) {
   text += "<br>" + myArray1[i] + "<br>";
   }
  }  
 }
```

```html
<p>Enter a height for our square<input type="text" id="textbox3"><button id="drawSqaure" onclick="drawSquare()">Draw Square</button></p>
<p id="output2">Output goes here</p>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Little implementation using a textarea.  It uses the number of rows to draw to know how many dots to draw, depending upon which row you are drawing.

```js
document.getElementById('rowCount').addEventListener('input', function(e){
  var rowCount = parseInt(e.target.value.trim() || '0', 10);
  var textarea = document.getElementsByTagName('textarea')[0];
  
  textarea.innerHTML = '';
  
  for (var i = 1; i <= rowCount; i++) {
    if (i > 1) textarea.innerHTML += "\n";
    
    textarea.innerHTML += '.'.repeat(rowCount - i);
    textarea.innerHTML += i;
    textarea.innerHTML += '.'.repeat(i - 1);
  }
});
```

```html
<input type="number" id="rowCount" value="0" min="0">
<textarea></textarea>
```

Answer (score 2):

To make it the way you clearly said on your question:

```
. . . . 1
. . . 2 .
. . 3 . .
. 4 . . .
5 . . . .
```

The solution is this:

```
$("#generate_square").click(function(){
    let number = $("#number").val();
  let square = $("#square_gen");
  let str = "";
  let number_shown = 1;
  for(var dcolumns = 1; dcolumns<=number; dcolumns++){
    for(var drows = 1; drows<=number; drows++){
        if( drows === number_shown ){
        str += number_shown+"  ";

      }else{
       str +="0  ";
      }
    }
    str += "<br>";
    number_shown++;
  }
  square.append(str);
});
```

Here is a fiddle of it working:

https://jsfiddle.net/ndpe671c/1/

Answer (score 1):

```js
function drawSquare() {
  var n = document.getElementById("textbox3").value;
  n = parseInt(n);
  var str = '<br/>';
  for (var i = 0; i < n; i++ ) {
    var x = n - 1;
    for (var j = x; j >= 0; j--) {
      if (j === i) {
        str += i;
      } else {
        str += '.';
      }
    }
    str += '<br/>';
  }
//  console.log(str);
  $('#output2').html(str);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <p>Enter a height for our square<input type="text" id="textbox3"><button id="drawSqaure" onclick="drawSquare()">Draw Square</button></p>
    <p id="output2">Output goes here</p>
```

I make it simpler with jquery. Check it and tell me, if it's what you want.